# Why is Erik Satie's Saraband 1 in A flat major?

Tags: enharmonics

Why is Erik Satie's Saraband 1 in A flat major?

There are so many F, C, and G flat accidentals through out the score it seem like it could have been notated in G sharp minor (enharmonic of A flat minor) with the tonic G sharp minor altered to be major at the beginning and end.

I get that altering the tonic chord would sort of contradict the key signature, but wouldn't the *majority* of the score then be much easier to read?

Maybe this is a sick joke from Satie, but his other scores don't seem to play musical enharomnic spelling jokes. His sense of humor came out in other ways.

https://imslp.org/wiki/3_Sarabandes_(Satie%2C_Erik)

Comment: Is there a source that clarifies A-flat *major*? IMSLP surprisingly has F minor listed (!).

Comment: Oh, I see that at IMSLP now. But, I'm saying A flat *major* because of 4 flats signature and the start/end chords are A flat major seven chords.

Comment: Wikipedia agrees with me ;-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarabandes#Music

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it *is* "a sick joke" about enharmonic spelling.  For a more flagrant example, see Satie's [Vexations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vexations).

Comment: If that is indeed the case, and if I made my own arrangement in `G#` minor, do you think it would be easier to read? I really would like to play this, but want something readable! Satie, why are you so cruel?!? :-)

Comment: Yes.  The Peters edition of the W.T.C. even inflicts this on the C# pieces, renotating them in D flat at the back of the volume.